# Setting Content-Type as application/json-patch+json in wso2

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to pass a payload with Content-Type application/json-patch+json from wso2 to an external api. I tried setting this as a transport header property, but it goes as application/json and not the type i want.

```
<header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json-patch+json"/>
```

I have also set the following property in axis2.xml file

```
<messageBuilder contentType="application/json-patch+json"  
                class="org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```

Can someone help me with this, i cannot figure out how to send the correct content type.

**Update**

This is the proxy i am using :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TestProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence> 
            <clone sequential="true">
                 <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                            <format>
                                [
                                    {
                                        "op":"add",
                                        "path":"/example/path",
                                        "value":{
                                            "attributes": "test-attribute"
                                            }
                                        
                                        ]
                            </format>
                            <args/>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        
                        <property name="ContentType" value="application/json-patch+json" scope="axis2"/>
                        <property name="Content-Type" value="application/json-patch+json" scope="transport"/>
                        
                        <log>
                            <property name="test-payload" expression="json-eval($)"/>
                        </log>
                        
                        <property expression="fn:concat('Bearer ','**xyz**')" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="patch" uri-template="https://api/v1/test">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <log>
                            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="patch-response"/>
                        </log>
                    </sequence>
                </target> 
                <target>
                    <!-- some other logic -->
                </target>
            </clone>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

these are the logs:-

```
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,155] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> PATCH /api/v1/test HTTP/1.1
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,155] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> Authorization: Bearer **xyz**
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,155] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> activityid: f6fabf50-e480-4f71-aacb-c8b8abe3e376
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,155] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept: */*
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,160] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> contentType: application/json-patch+json
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,160] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Type: application/json
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,160] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> SOAPAction:
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,160] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,163] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,163] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,192] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "PATCH /api/v1/test HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,192] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Authorization: Bearer **xyz**[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,192] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "activityid: f6fabf50-e480-4f71-aacb-c8b8abe3e376[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,195] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,197] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "contentType: application/json-patch+json[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,198] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,198] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "SOAPAction: [\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,200] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,200] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,201] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,201] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,203] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "236[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,203] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[{"op":"add","path":"/example/path","value":{"attributes":{"test-attribute"}}}][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,203] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,203] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,613] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,613] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2023 05:16:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,613] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,613] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Length: 48[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,615] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,615] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Vary: Origin[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,615] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,615] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,615] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,617] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: master-only[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-28 10:46:18,617] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: Which product version are you using?

Comment: @ycr version 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the following two properties.

```xml
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="ContentType" value="application/json-patch+json" scope="axis2"/>
```

---

**Update**

The above should actually work. If you have set the messageType property the message will be built as a JSON content and the Content-type header would be picked up from the `ContentType` property.

Since it didn't work try to change the message builders and formatters. Message builder is activated when the message comes into MI and Formatters are activated when it's going out. Add the following to the `deployment.toml`

```ini
[[custom_message_formatters]]
class = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
content_type = "application/json-patch+json"

[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
content_type = "application/json-patch+json"
```

---

**Update 02**

Here is a super Simple example that works without changes to the MessageFormatters.

**API**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/test" name="TestAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/users">
        <inSequence>
            <log/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"message" : "Hello"}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="ContentType" value="application/json-patch+json" scope="axis2"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Requeset**

```
curl -v --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8290/test/users'
```

**Response**

```
➜  ~ curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8290/test/users' -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8290...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8290 (#0)
> GET /test/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8290
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< activityid: 71c5ecbf-7c7a-4216-873f-85315e58982e
< Accept: */*
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Host: localhost:8290
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
< Content-Type: application/json-patch+json; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 22:37:20 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"message" : "Hello"}%
```

As you can see the content type is set to `< Content-Type: application/json-patch+json;`

Comment: No, this did not work. I want to manipulate the property with name="Content-Type" which should be a transport level header to the api.

Comment: @Miley check the update in the answer.

Comment: This did not work too@ycr

Comment: @Miley add your complete integration code and the configurations.

Comment: @Miley I added a working sample for you in the updated answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with the proxy i am using

Comment: @Miley Eve the example you provided works for me. Is the example I provided working for you?

Comment: its working for me now. I added the formatter and builder in axis2 and also set messageType, ContentType property just before calling the api. For Some reason the authorization properties i set before calling the api were hindering the contentType. Setting it just before the call worked. Thanks for your inputs!! @ycr